# CMake error while executing catkin_make on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Jade

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, cmake, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and just getting it installed and configured using the method here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

I am a beginner and have minimal knowledge of these things, so it would be helpful if someone could present a simplified solution that would solve my problem. 
I can run everything correctly till I encounter the command `catkin_make` which produces the following error:

```
Base path: /home/tejas/catkin_ws
Source space:
/home/tejas/catkin_ws/src Build space:
/home/tejas/catkin_ws/build Devel
space: /home/tejas/catkin_ws/devel
Install space:
/home/tejas/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/tejas/catkin_ws/src
-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/tejas/catkin_ws/devel
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/tejas/catkin_ws/install
-G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/tejas/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/tejas/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/jade
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/jade
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/tejas/anaconda/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/tejas/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7 Traceback (most
recent call last):   File
"/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py",
line 98, in <module>
    main()   File "/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py",
line 90, in main
    package = parse_package(args.package_xml)   File
"/home/tejas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py",
line 317, in parse_package
    return parse_package_string(f.read(),
filename)   File
"/home/tejas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py",
line 450, in parse_package_string
    raise InvalidPackage('Error(s) in %s:%s' % (filename, ''.join(['\n- %s'
% e for e in errors])))
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage:
Invalid package manifest
"/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml":
Error(s) in
/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml:
- The manifest must not contain the following tags: depend,
build_export_depend,
buildtool_export_depend CMake Error at
/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11
(message):  
execute_process(/home/tejas/anaconda/bin/python
"/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
"/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
"/home/tejas/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
returned error code 1 Call Stack (most
recent call first):  
/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63
(safe_execute_process)  
/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151
(_catkin_package_xml)  
/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20
(include)   CMakeLists.txt:52
(find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
"/home/tejas/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
"/home/tejas/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215473/cmake-error-while-executing-catkin_make-on-ubuntu-14.04-with-ros-jade/) by [tejas](https://answers.ros.org/users/23508/tejas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Failing to find a solution, I decided to switch to my default python interpreter from the anaconda version I was using. That solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [tejas](https://answers.ros.org/users/23508/tejas/) with karma: 26 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2018-02-21**:
Obviously, that would solve your problem, but it doesn't answer your question.

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2021-08-03**:
Should not be marked as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following this guide and adapting it to Ubuntu, I was able to solve the same problem.
[Prepare ROS libraries and anaconda environment for raspberry-pi](https://gist.github.com/mitmul/538315c68c2069f16f11)

`conda` versions of  `ros` and `catkin`'s packages are very old. remove them and install them with  `pip`.

Do:

```
pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall six vcstools
```

if you get an error during this, install `setuptools` using

```
conda install setuptools
```

If `rosdep update` fails, reinstall `catking_pkg` with `pip`.

Referring to this might also help, but instead of deleting the folder as it says, I reinstalled `catkin_pkg`:
[problem-with-catkin_make](http://answers.ros.org/question/56873/problem-with-catkin_make/?answer=56928#post-id-56928)

---

Originally posted by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) with karma: 31 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2